# TComboBox: add items in "reversed order"

Tags: combobox, lazarus, freepascal

`TComboBox.Items.Add` adds an item "at the end" of the list (at n+1 with n being the last index before edding the new item):

```
0: Item1
1: Itme2
2: Item3
3: New Item
```

But I want to add the item at n=0, with all the other items moving up one index:

```
0: New Item
1: Item1
2: Itme2
3: Item3
```

Currently I'm using this code, which works well:

```
ComboBox1.Items.Add(strSomeNewItem);
ComboBox1.Items.Move(ComboBox1.Items.Count-1,0);
```

I was just wondering if I overlooked a scenario in which it might cause problems?! Or maybe there is a better command I overlooked?! 
(The [Lazarus Component Library](https://lazarus-ccr.sourceforge.io/docs/lcl/index.html) is currently down, so most of the links in my search engine come up with an error).

Cheers!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`Insert()`](https://www.freepascal.org/docs-html/rtl/classes/tstrings.insert.html).

```
ComboBox1.Items.Insert(0, strSomeNewItem);
```